# How to include a health-check endpoint in a Azure Machine Learning Model deployed as an AKS Webservice?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

When we deploy a model using Azure Machine Learning Service, we need a scoring script with at least two functions `init` which is run once when a model is first deployed and a `run` function which is run against any data we want to be scored.

The endpoint for this is: `http://<IP-Address>/api/v1/service/<Webservice-Name>/score`

Is there a way to include a health-check function in the deployed web service? Maybe adding another function `healthcheck()` and a corresponding endpoint `http://<IP-Address>/api/v1/service/<Webservice-Name>/health` which when pinged sends us a custom JSON containing information about the health of our service. This may even include information about the Azure Health Check too:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the Azure Machine Learning SDK has to show the properties of the class Webservice. I haven't found any mention to this issue online.

To reproduce fully the experiment, you have to install AML SDK:

```
pip install azureml-core
```

And get the workspace:

```
# get the workspace
subscription_id = '<your_subscription_id>'
resource_group = '<your_resource_group>'
workspace_name = '<your_workspace_name>'
ws = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)
```

Using the [Webservice Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.webservice(class)?view=azure-ml-py), it should work. I have 3 services, but I can't see the status:

```
# this should work, but it isn't returning the state
for service in Webservice.list(workspace= ws):
    print('Service Name: {} - {}'.format(service.name, service.state)) 
>> Service Name: akstest - None
>> Service Name: regression-model-1 - None
>> Service Name: xgboost-classification-1 - None
```

Using an intermediate step using the _get() method, it works:

```
# this works
for service in Webservice.list(workspace= ws):
    service_properties = Webservice._get(workspace= ws, name = service.name)
    print('Service Name: {} - {}'.format(service_properties['name'], service_properties['state']))
>> Service Name: akstest - Failed
>> Service Name: regression-model-1 - Healthy
>> Service Name: xgboost-classification-1 - Healthy
```

Comment: Yes, this is the perfect way of finding the health of the service. I am more interested in adding a separate endpoint itself. `<URI>/score` for scoring input payload and `<URI>/health` for pinging and finding the health of the service. The consumer of the API can ping this `<URI>/health` not me (the API Creator/ Publisher).

Comment: As far as I understand, you can't add new method such as /health in the deployment of the inference service. However, you add a parameter to the run function to specify the type of response. For instance, responseType = 1, runs the code I've provided, resposeType = 0 does the inference. But this won't be helpful, once if the service is unhealthy you won't be able to get a response. By the way, this service status is actually the deployment status, so even if you were able to implement a new method, you will get a response only when the deployment is healthy.

Comment: My suggestions to you are: 1) impement a service in the client using the SDK as I showed in the reply - These methods are not there just for developing, but also for consuming on the client. This way you won't depend on the service itself to let you know if the service is unhealthy, but in the workspace. 2) Consume information from either the Azure Application Insights associated with the workspace or publish the telemetry to an Azure Monitor and consume it.

Comment: Yes, hooking Azure Application Insights/ Azure Monitor should solve the visibility into the health of the service.